# Can JNI be made to honour wildcard expansion in the classpath?

Tags: java, c, unix, java-native-interface, classpath

I have a C binary that calls out to Java via JNI. I set CLASSPATH to somedir/* to pick up all the jars in somedir.

When I run the binary, a required class definition cannot be found. When I run

```
java that.class's.name
```

from the same command line, the class is successfully found. If I explicitly add all the jars in somedir/ to the classpath, everything works great, but that leads to a *very* long classpath which I'd like to avoid.

Does a JVM executed via JNI honour wildcard expansion of the classpath? Can it be made to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out the answer by reading the hotspot source code.

Only paths passed via either `CLASSPATH` or `-cp` / `-classpath` are subject to wildcard expansion. These are then passed as a system property to the running JVM via `-Djava.class.path`.

You tell a JNI-invoked JVM about a classpath via a `JVMOptions` structure, which may include `-Djava.class.path` but `-classpath` will not *necessarily* be honoured (and in practice, isn't by the hotspot implementation). Since `java.class.path` is directly passed to the JVM as a system property, it doesn't get wildcard expanded and therefore wildcards won't work.

Answer (score 3):

No. No, it cannot. Using JNI doesn't help.

The way you would do this is by implementing your own class loader (in Java), but that class loader would have to be in the wildcard-free CLASSPATH.

You could, of course, set the CLASSPATH to its expanded form *before* invoking the JVM. That would work and could be done via a shell script (no JNI needed).

Comment: Thanks, and good suggestions re: the class loader. To be clear, it's using JNI that makes the wildcard expansion impossible; otherwise in Java >= 1.5 all paths in $CLASSPATH would be expanded for jars.